# How to scale carousel when you resize browser size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have got a Bootstrap carousel with 3 images (480x320px). Width of carousel itself set to 480px. How to scale carousel when you resize browser size?

```
.carousel{
    width: 480px;
    margin: auto;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the width of your `.carousel` class as `100%`..

You need to make the below change to your CSS,

```
.carousel{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

However if you want keep them at 480x320px initially and want to handle them while the browser is getting resized, then you will need to go for media queries.

```
/* For devices which are smaller than 960 pixels */
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
   //Write your CSS here.
}

/* For Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
   //Write your CSS here.
}

/* For all mobiles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   //Write your CSS here.
}

/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait  */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
   //Write your CSS here.
}

/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
   //Write your CSS here.
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would like to keep carousel/images displayed 480x320px on the full browser screen but when you start resizing browser carousel/images would also shrink.

Comment: Then, you need to opt for writing media queries. Check my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that a simple width:100%; on the css, and apply img-responsive to it may fix it.

Let me know!